# Why can't I use a function returning a compile-time constant as a constant?

Tags: rust

```
let arr0 = [0u8; 15];
let arr1 = [0u8; arr0.len()]; // this fails
```

I think the compiler should be able to determine the length of arr0 as a compile time constant, no? Still this is flagged as error saying that variable found instead of constant integer.

1. Why?
2. Is there constexpr (C++) function in Rust?

Version:

```
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (ecf8c64e1 2015-03-21) (built 2015-03-22)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because it hasn't been implemented yet. Extending the subset of Rust that counts as constant expressions can be done backwards-compatibly, so there's no rush to do so before 1.0, and it's not even settled how it should be done (how much should be allowed, whether there should be a `constexpr` mechanism and how powerful it should be, etc).

In the meantime, macros and syntax extensions cover many of the same use cases (and the latter are strictly more powerful than `constexpr` ever will be).

Comment: Without rush there is time to do it right, so it's hopefully better in the long run