# Power expression in a constant

Tags: rust

I have the following code

```
pub const EXP: u32 = 4;
pub const POW: u32 = 3u32.pow(EXP);
```

This fails to compile since I'm using an expression:

```
src/t.rs:4:22: 4:35 error: constant contains unimplemented expression type [E0019]
src/t.rs:4 pub const POW: u32 = 3u32.pow(EXP);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can I have this value (3 ** EXP) be a constant in any other way? I can only think, at the moment, to have a function

```
#[inline(always)]
pub fn POW() -> { 3u32.pow(EXP); }
```

but I was wondering if it can be done with the constants as well.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29250386/155423?

Comment: Yes, this is an almost exact duplicate of that.

Comment: Oh! I had not realized we finally had a user with Mjolnir in the Rust tag! Gratz Vladimir :)

Comment: [This](http://rust-ci.org/Kimundi/lazy-static.rs/doc/lazy_static/) is a helpful crate for defining variables that get initialized at runtime.